# Highcharts export to PDF - results in "cannot display webpage" using IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, pdf, highcharts

Trying to export Highcharts to PDF using IE9. I have tried the following code, which results in "IE Page cannot be displayed" error. Can anyone please guide me to fix the bug? Really appreciate your time and help.

My Code:

```
      function getData() {
              var myChart;
              var options = {
                    chart : {
                        renderTo : 'container',
                        type : 'area',
                    },
                   xAxis : {
                        categories : []
                    },
                   exporting: {
                        enabled : true,
                         type: 'application/pdf'
                   },
                   series : []
              };

        $.get(url, function(xml) {
            var $xml = $(xml);
            $xml.find('categories month').each(
                    function(i, category) {
                        options.xAxis.categories.push($(category).text());
                    });
            $xml.find('Type Series').each(
                            function(i,series){
                                var seriesOptions = {
                                    name : $(series).find('name').text(),
                                    data : [],
                                };
                              $(series).find('data point').each(
                                    function(i,point){
                                        seriesOptions.data.push(parseInt($(point).text()));
                                });
                              options.series.push(seriesOptions);
                            });
                    myChart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });

        Highcharts.getSVG = function(charts) {
                var svgArr = [],
                    top = 0,
                    width = 0;

                $.each(charts, function(i, chart) {
                    var svg = chart.getSVG();
                    svg = svg.replace('<svg', '<g transform="translate(0,' + top + ')" ');
                    svg = svg.replace('</svg>', '</g>');

                    top += chart.chartHeight;
                    width = Math.max(width, chart.chartWidth);

                    svgArr.push(svg);
                });

                return '<svg height="'+ top +'" width="' + width + '" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' + svgArr.join('') + '</svg>';
            };

            Highcharts.exportCharts = function(charts, options) {
                // Merge the options

                options = Highcharts.merge(Highcharts.getOptions().exporting, options);

                // Post to export server
                Highcharts.post(options.url, {
                    filename: options.filename || 'chart',
                    type: options.type,
                    width: options.width,
                    svg: Highcharts.getSVG(charts)
                });
            };
            $('#export').click(function() {
                Highcharts.exportCharts([myChart]);
            });
        }



<body>
<button id="export">Export all</button>
<div id="container" class="myChart" style="width: 100%; height: 500px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Are other formats exported successfully? Could you post a live example, like jsFiddle? To make it easier to replicate you could hard-code data. Is standard exporting (provided by default exporting module) working for you?

Comment: @Kacper Madej Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/1wn9u26r/ 
Can you please guide, where i'm going wrong!!

Comment: 1 - you are loading Highcharts multiple times - do it only onec - see error in bowser console (Developer Tools). 2 - you code is also not working in Chrome - myChart is defined in wrong scope and is not defined when trying to create svg for export. Here is a working example - http://jsfiddle.net/9zzd6bc7/1/ Can you check it in IE9?

Comment: @Kacper Madej Oh Thanks for the info.. I have changed the scope of the variable `myChart`, and i am not sure how to load the chart only once. Even if i use $.each() it will load the chart once right? I tried running your fiddle in IE9, but it didnt work, got this error `SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'getSVG': object is null or undefined ` . Can you please help?

Comment: I meant loading Highcharts library multiple times, not a chart. The error you are getting should point to some variable that is not defined or is null - you could check what that variable is and why is it not defined or null.

Comment: Thanks! I am getting the rendered value for `svgArr` but after that the page refreshes to `Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage`. I get this error. What would be the problem? Please help me figure this one.

Comment: @Kacper Madej My `SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'getSVG': object is null or undefined` error got resolved and i get the rendered value of svgArr, but ` IE cannot display the webpage` error is thrown, once its comes out of the `Highcharts.getSVG` function. Do you have any idea why this happens in IE9

Comment: I do not know what code exactly you are using, but I just tested code from my last send to you in comment fiddle and PDF. Steps: get html content of iframe from [view-source:http://fiddle.jshell.net/9zzd6bc7/1/show/light/](view-source:http://fiddle.jshell.net/9zzd6bc7/1/show/light/), replace $.get with hardcoded data to isolate single issue you have, remove last commas from objects to make code work in IE9, run file (can be done locally) in IE9 and after chart is loaded press the button - PDF can be confirmed to download. I am not able to recreate your problem.